# Anynomus posts in my website drupal

Tags: users

im just new on drupal, i noticed that some posts in my content of my website are submitted by anynomus ( not verified ) user , it came with no type or author . 
is it hacked ?? or how can i stop these posts on my website.
the role at my website required to be verified   before publishing BUT these posts came published already

plz help here is a screenshot with the black rectangle arround the posts which i mean.
[image]

Comment: the fact that there is no content type name makes me believe that you got hacked.

Comment: what shall i do now ?? :(

Comment: **[Your Drupal site got hacked. Now what?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2365547)**

Comment: **[Video: How to Restore Your Hacked Site](https://modulesunraveled.com/blog/how-restore-your-hacked-site)**

Comment: thnx alot dear , the content type was a wiki , i removed the wiki from the content type which i dont use,

Comment: for that it doesnt appear as a type ..

Answer (score 0):

with the Permissions you can deny anything to anonymous (not registered) users you don't want them to do.
Also this may help.